# Factorial of a number not returning expected value

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math, factorial

I'm trying to pass a test case as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class SolutionTests
{

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var solution = new Solution();

        Assert.AreEqual(solution.Factorial(5), 120);
    }

}
```

My code is returning 3125 and the expected answer is 120.

My code is below and I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Solution
{
    public int Factorial(int input)
    {
        int result = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
        {
            result = result * input;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

I have looked at other similar examples but I'm struggling to understand them due to my learning difficulties can someone please help

Comment: The expected value is the first argument to `Assert.AreEqual` so your code is returning 3125 and the expected result is 120. You need to multiply by `i` instead of `input` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: `5! == 120`.  Where are you getting `3125`?

Comment: @Tripp he's doing 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should multiply the result on `i` and not on `input` in the `for` loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
{
    result = result * i;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an error in Factorial function. You are using input instead of iterator. It should be rewritte like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Solution
{
    public int Factorial(int input)
    {
        int result = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```